# How to output Veezi JSON subarray?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, element

I'm working with the Veezi API and this is some of their JSON output:

```
[{
    "Id":"ST00000032",
    "Title":"Avatar",
    "People":[
         {
             "Id":"0000000032",
             "FirstName":"Sam",
             "LastName":"Worthington",
             "Role":"Actor"
         },
         {
             "Id":"HO00000176",
             "FirstName":"James",
             "LastName":"Cameron",
             "Role":"Director"
         },
         {
             "Id":"HO00000578",
             "FirstName":"Sigourney",
             "LastName":"Weaver",
             "Role":"Actor"
        }
    ],
    "AudioLanguage":"English"
}]
```

I'm building a string in PHP and so far (where `$theArray` is my JSON decoded array, this is the code I have:

```
$allShows .= '<p class="details">With: ';
foreach($theArray['People'] as $key => $value){
    $allShows .= $value->FirstName.' '.$value->LastName.' ('.$value->Role.') <br>';
}
$allShows .= '</p>';
```

I'm not getting any values, just the embedded parentheses around "Role". The right number of parentheses are being returned, so I'm pretty sure I'm looping correctly. Can anyone spot my issue?

Comment: whats `print_r($theArray)` look like, it looks like you got an array of objects, so json_decode will give you an array of arrays, your need two foreach's or if you only want the first `foreach($theArray[0]['People'] as ...)`.

Comment: If you've decoded the JSON string into an array instead of an object, all nested JSON objects will also be arrays. In that case, you should use `$value['FirstName']` instead of `$value->FirstName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the whole json string as an array.  If you uncomment my `var_export()` call, you can see that the array begins with a zero indexed element.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a583745daf1f134b5b43ec18f01a9476ef712f1))

```
$json='[
{
    "Id":"ST00000032",
    "Title":"Avatar",
    "People":[
         {
             "Id":"0000000032",
             "FirstName":"Sam",
             "LastName":"Worthington",
             "Role":"Actor"
         },
         {
             "Id":"HO00000176",
             "FirstName":"James",
             "LastName":"Cameron",
             "Role":"Director"
         },
         {
             "Id":"HO00000578",
             "FirstName":"Sigourney",
             "LastName":"Weaver",
             "Role":"Actor"
        }
    ],
    "AudioLanguage":"English"    }
]';

//var_export(json_decode($json,true));

$allShows='<p class="details">With: ';
foreach(json_decode($json,true)[0]['People'] as $value){
    $allShows.="{$value['FirstName']} {$value['LastName']} ({$value['Role']})<br>";
}
$allShows.='</p>';
echo $allShows;
```

Output:

```
<p class="details">With: Sam Worthington (Actor)<br>James Cameron (Director)<br>Sigourney Weaver (Actor)<br></p>
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to work with an array of objects, you can use this:

```
$allShows='<p class="details">With: ';
foreach(json_decode($json)[0]->People as $value){
    $allShows.="{$value->FirstName} {$value->LastName} ({$value->Role})<br>";
}
$allShows.='</p>';
echo $allShows;  // same result
```

---

If it were my project, I wouldn't want that last `<br>` tag before `</p>`, so I'd use something like this:

```
foreach(json_decode($json)[0]->People as $value){
    $set[]="{$value->FirstName} {$value->LastName} ({$value->Role})";
}
echo '<p class="details">With: ',implode('<br>',$set),'</p>';
```

Output:

```
<p class="details">With: Sam Worthington (Actor)<br>James Cameron (Director)<br>Sigourney Weaver (Actor)</p>
```